# Is there a possibility to have embeded config only for specific configuration in .NET desktop application?

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, settings, embedded-resource

a desktop application (WPF, .NET 4.6.2) has lots of settings in app.config. The settings have different values for specific configurations: App.Debug.config and App.Release.config. QA engineers are happy to change values in App.Debug.config and test different application modes in the testing environment. However, for security reasons, I would like to prevent a production user to change any parameter. At the moment, a user can just edit the config file, restart app and use the app in unexpected mode.

I could move settings to embedded resources (or just hard code in some configuration class), but in this case, QA cannot change parameters dynamically and lost testing flexibility.

It would be nice to configure the app and build process to have App.Debug.config as is for Debug configuration. And to have an embedded App.Release.config for Release configuration. I'm not sure how to achieve that, maybe you have an idea how it could be implemented?

Comment: I am not entirely sure, which bit is the most important.
You could consider encrypting the release profile? Then you can only modify it if you have the decryption key? I mean, it does seem a little excessive, if you don't trust your own people to not, make a mistake like that? But you do what you want to in your company :)

I would setup Launch configurations with an Environment variable. 
Then I would make that variable responsible for picking which app.config file gets loaded. 

And if production is chosen, then setup the pipeline (for a release deployment) to know the description key.

Comment: Or something like that?

Comment: I think that even a simple hash would suffice, since as you describe the Release configuration would be included in the release itself.
This could be done in a thousand ways in a CI. 
imo just check if the hash is the expected one otherwise open a "you tampered with the config and broke everything" message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be fairly easy to prevent users from making any changes.

1. Make sure your settings uses the "Application" scope
2. Install your application in the program-files folder
3. Make sure your users are not running with administrator permissions

That should prevent any users from making any changes to the configuration files.

Keep in mind that most users will not make random changes to application settings, or registry settings, or anything else they do not understand. And if they do, you can tell them to blame themselves and to reinstall.

If your users are in fact running as administrators, there is nothing you can do to really prevent them from making changes, you can only make it more difficult. So you should really not store anything security sensitive that the user should not have access to if the user is an administrator.

If making things more difficult is sufficient for you, you might want to consider some alternative to the built in settings. For example something like:

1. Create a settings-class with default-values for all the configuration you might want. Ensure this is serializable. Create an object of this class.
2. Check if some file exist at startup. Use `#if DEBUG` to only run this in debug

   1. If the file exist, deserialize and set it as the current setting object
   2. If it does not, serialize the current settings object to the file
3. Distribute the this settings object to all components in your application. An dependency injection container might help with this.

Using something like json serialization also has the advantage that you can serialize more complex objects.